# Very Simple Print Button

Tags: c#, blazor, radzen

Converting an older application into a Blazor Web Application. The older has a very basic PRINT Link as follows:

```
  <a class="print" href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

Is there a way to do this same (simple and easy web page print) by using a Radzen Button?  I can't seem to figure out how to do the href within the Radzen Button

Here is an example of a Radzen Button that is also on the page.  This calls a function called DetailsShowStatus (C#).  Is there a simple C# print option I can use?  Or - can I somehow call the jscript 'window:print' from within the Radzen button?

```
<RadzenButton Button Text="Edit Status" Click=@(args => DetailsShowStatus(carPK))  ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" ></RadzenButton>
```

Comment: You need to inject a `IJSRuntime` property on your page and then call a javascript method from it (define a JS method that calls `window.print()` and call it with `JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("PrintMethod")`... can't write a full answer now but this should be enough for you to google it 

Comment: Thank you @Jcl for this start.  It really helped put me on the right path!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a demo page (based on what @Jcl suggested):

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime _js
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="m-2 p-2">
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.PrintMe> Print Me</button>
</div>


@code {
    private async Task PrintMe()
        => await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.print");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MrC aka Shaun Curtis!  That's exactly what I needed to see.  Was able to implement this very easily and does exactly what I was asking to do.

Comment: Thanks again!  <RadzenButton Button Text="Print" Click=this.PrintMe  ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" ></RadzenButton>   is now working like a charm!